# Removing Single View from a layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view

I'm trying to remove a single view from layout but it is not being removed.
But, when i call `removeAll`, it does remove them all.

Here is the code:

```
for (int subspe = 0; subspe < totalSubSpe; subspe++) {
    View childSubSpe = 
          BasicInfoUpdateDocProfile.ll_custom_for_supspecialist.getChildAt(subspe);
    TextView subSpecialityId = (TextView) childSubSpe.findViewById(R.id.tv_speciality_id);
    TextView specialistId = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
    String speID = specialistId.getText().toString();
    String subSepId = subSpecialityId.getText().toString();
    Log.e("TAG", "the the the the id is: speciality " + speID);
    Log.e("TAG", "the the the the id is: sub speiciality " + subSepId);

    if (speID.equals(subSepId)) {
        //removing sub qualificaiton
        Log.e("TAG", "It is Equal subspecialist ");
        ViewGroup par = (ViewGroup) childSubSpe.getParent();
        par.removeView(childSubSpe);
        //BasicInfoUpdateDocProfile.ll_custom_for_supspecialist.removeView(childSubSpe);
        BasicInfoUpdateDocProfile.ll_custom_for_supspecialist.
            removeView((View)childSubSpe.getParent());
        // BasicInfoUpdateDocProfile.ll_custom_for_supspecialist.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```